# Is it safe to kill ANALYZE TABLE query on a MyISAM table?

Tags: mysql, myisam, mysql-5.1

I have a huge MyISAM table that is blocking my application. I frequently find `ANALYZE TABLE` queries running on that table. I **guess** that's because a join is being performed on the table or at least an index is being used, I'm not sure.

So I'm thinking to run a `OPTIMIZE TABLE` query on the table to speed things up. But there are currently multiple `ANALAYZE TABLE` queries locking the table, so is it safe to kill such queries ? I couldn't find enough information on mysql's documentation for that matter..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to know is what [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) does.

For a MyISAM table `mydb.mytable`, [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) traverses all the indexes in the `mytable.MYI` file, reads all BTREE pages, computes statistics, and stores in them in the information_schema, specifically [`STATISTICS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statistics-table.html). You can see it when you run one of the following:

- `SHOW INDEXES FROM mydb.mytable;`
- `SELECT * FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';`

[`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) is a read-only operation and does issue a table-wide read lock.

## ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION

Yes, you can kill [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) and wait briefly for the read lock to be released. However, there is a significant penalty. Because the index statistics will not be completely computed, the MySQL Query Optimizer will take rather bad guesses at generating EXPLAIN plans of queries against that table.

## SUGGESTIONS

#### SUGGESTION #1 : Delay `ANALYZE TABLE`

If you want to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable` without doing the `ANALYZE TABLE` operation, do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable RENAME mydb.mytable_opt;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_opt ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_opt RENAME mydb.mytable;
```

This will rename the table, perform the defragmentation, and rename it back.

You could do it in one line as well

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

If you want to run [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) later on, set up a cron job to run it in every midnight or perhaps once a week. You will have to do this inevitably if you expect queries against your table to perform well after an optimization.

#### SUGGESTION #2 : Change the MyISAM table to InnoDB

During the generation of an EXPLAIN plan, InnoDB will perform reads against the index pages of a table by traversing 2-3 levels of nonleaf nodes and literally approximate (or really guess) the cardinality of all column levels. You can tell this is happening to an InnoDB table when you run `SHOW INDEXES FROM mydb.mytable;` because the cardinality changes with each run.

In light of this, you can simply run

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and that's it. Even if you ran `ANALYZE TABLE` on an InnoDB table, the statistics can get rather stale. By default, [`innodb_stats_on_metadata`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata) is already disabled in MySQL 5.6. If you have MySQL 5.5 and prior, you can disable the update of the statistics by doing this:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0;
```

You will still have to bite the bullet and run [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) sometime downstream if the InnoDB table experiences high INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs. Otherwise, the MySQL Query Optimizer will take bad guesses at EXPLAIN plans.